# How to scale a Path with fixed values to dynamic Composable size?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple `Box` Composable which I wanna clip to a custom shape, but whenever I try it, the shape's size remains pretty rigid and small. I've tried scaling on the path level using `Matrix()`, but to no avail. Here's the sample -

```
const val clockHand = "M0 80.52L2 86l2-5.48V2.74C4 1.83 3.6 0 2 0S0 1.83 0 2.74v77.78Z"
val clockHandShape = object : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {
        return Outline.Generic(PathParser.createPathFromPathData(clockHand).asComposePath())
    }
}

Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .background(Color.Green)
                            .clip(clockHandShape)
                            .width(30.dp)
                            .height(50.dp)
                            .background(Color(0xFFFF007A))
                            .layoutId("hourHand")
) {}
```

As a control, you can replace the custom shape with a pre-defined one like `RectangleShape` or `CircleShape` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clipping doesn't make size modifiers ineffective. Shape is created using the intrinsic pixel size coming from the values that creates that drawable.

All you need to do is get intrinsic size of Path using getBounds().size and scale to Composable size when creating the shape using matrix.postScale.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {

    val clockHand = "M0 80.52L2 86l2-5.48V2.74C4 1.83 3.6 0 2 0S0 1.83 0 2.74v77.78Z"
    val path = PathParser.createPathFromPathData(clockHand).asComposePath()
    val pathSize = path.getBounds().size

    val clockHandShape = object : Shape {
        override fun createOutline(
            size: Size,
            layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
            density: Density
        ): Outline {

            val matrix = android.graphics.Matrix()
            matrix.postScale(
                size.width / pathSize.width, size.height / pathSize.height
            )
            path.asAndroidPath().transform(matrix)

            return Outline.Generic(path)
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(clockHandShape)
            .size(90.dp, 150.dp)
            .background(Color(0xFFFF007A))
            .layoutId("hourHand")
    ) {}
}
```

Comment: Doc Thrace! You are always there to help man, highly appreciate it. I'll add a bounty to this question in a while, give you a treat. Keep up the great job doc

Comment: Hey @RichardOnslowRoper, how are you doing? I'm actually quite busy for the time being but i woke up early so i had an hour before work to check out some questions. Happy to come across one that is yours. Save your bounty for the next one, have a good day.

Comment: I'm doing just fine, but is it weird that I want to give you the bounty even more now? Anyway good thing you're busy. I'm losing my mind because of lack of stuff to do.