# How to adjust size of Jetpack compose GenericShape

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have defined approx. 20 GenericShape from SVG path and I wanted to expose them as clickable, independents but consistant (relatively positionned) buttons.

Each GenericShape is define as follow:

```kotlin
    val shape_0 = GenericShape { size, layoutDirection ->
        val width: Float = size.width // not used here
        val height: Float = size.height // not used here

        moveTo(147.5f, 320f)
        cubicTo(150f, 335f, 170f, 335f, 172.5f, 320f)
        cubicTo(180f, 245f, 186f, 213f, 175f, 180f)
        cubicTo(165f, 140f, 155f, 140f, 145f, 180f)
        cubicTo(134f, 213f, 140f, 245f, 147.5f, 320f)
        close()
    }
```

And each button like this:

```kotlin
 Button(
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Red, ),
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Black),
        onClick = {},
        shape = shape_0
    ) {}
```

for a single button, it look like this:

[initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8h8J.png)

First of all, Border are not applied consistently, whatever the elevation (any advice appreciated).

But most of all, If I try to put all buttons (all of them correctly positioned, in absolute) in a Box and try to fillMaxSize like this:

```kotlin
    Box(
// =============> Modifier: 
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Cyan)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val shape_0 = GenericShape { size, layoutDirection ->
            moveTo(147.5f, 320f)
            ...same path...
            close()
        }
        Button(
// =============> Modifier: 
           modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Red),
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Black),
            onClick = {},
            shape = shape_0
        ) {}

        val shape_1 = GenericShape { size, layoutDirection ->
            moveTo(155f, 140f)
            cubicTo(115f, 70f, 145f, 70f, 160f, 70f)
            cubicTo(175f, 70f, 205f, 70f, 165f, 140f)
            quadraticBezierTo(160f, 145f, 155f, 140f)
            close()
        }
        Button(            
// =============> Modifier: 
           modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Blue),
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Black),
            onClick = {},
            shape = shape_1
        ) {}
        // and so on for the next 18 shapes + buttons
    }
```

It does not change anything for any buttons size (except the Cyan background of course):

[two button defined with shapes not expected size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNBaQ.png)

**I would really appreciate avoid having to readjust the path depending on width and height of parent as I need to adjust hundreds of parameters with the correct ratio.**

Is it possible to adjust the size of all buttons in the same Box (or other component) to adjust them all together?

I have tried to use a Surface, to play with modifier or clipToBounds but the only change was that from time to time, buttons behaviours were broken

Comment: It happens because in the shape you are **not** using the size parameter. All the value are static.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti  Yes indeed: I want to avoid some kind of widthRatio = size.width/_INITIAL_SVG_WIDTH and apply this ratio to every number in each part of each path as I have around 550 of them. Ils there a way to define a canvas and adjust all component in it even if they have been absolutely places? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to draw into Path instead of shape and get Outline from path. Paths can be scaled using matrix from their intrinsic sizes to Composable size you want to draw inside.

You can refer this answer for details.
[Clipping to this shape makes all the size modifiers ineffective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75458039/clipping-to-this-shape-makes-all-the-size-modifiers-ineffective/75467992#75467992)

```
val path = Path().apply {
    // Add your drawings here
//            cubicTo()
//            quadraticBezierTo()
}
val pathSize = path.getBounds().size


val shape = object : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {

        val matrix = android.graphics.Matrix()
        matrix.postScale(
            size.width / pathSize.width, size.height / pathSize.height
        )
        path.asAndroidPath().transform(matrix)

        return Outline.Generic(path)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps me a lot to get a cleaner result. I still have a border issue but that is another point ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75796401/how-to-have-a-regular-border-for-a-button-with-genericshape-in-jetpack-compose))