# How to have a regular border for a button with GenericShape in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have defined a button with a custom GenericShape in jetpack compose.

This button has a border defined with a width of 1.dp

```kotlin
    val shape = GenericShape { size, _ ->
        moveTo(235f, 15f)
        cubicTo(250f, 30f, 260f, 60f, 240f, 65f)
        cubicTo(195f, 75f, 195f, 50f, 200f, 35f)
        cubicTo(205f, 20f, 220f, 0f, 235f, 15f)
        close()
    }

    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface),
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface),
        onClick = {},
        shape = shape,
        elevation = null,
        content = {},
    )
```

And here is the result:
[unregular border image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu7sh.png)

As you can see, the border is not regular but it has a kind of shadow effect (the elevation is null here)...

Is there a way to get a **regular** border on the button?

**--- Edit 21/03/2023 ---**

thanks to @Thracian comment, I have changed the way I create and scale the path in a much more convenient way:

```kotlin
val shape = GenericShape { size, _ ->
    val path = PathParser.createPathFromPathData("M 235 15 C 250 30 260 60 240 65 C 195 75 195 50 200 35 C 205 20 220 0 235 15 Z")
    val matrix = Matrix()
    // This SVG data is in a [0, 0, initialSVG_Width, initialSVG_Height] coordinate space
    val scale = minOf(size.width / initialSVG_Width, size.height / initialSVG_Height)
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale)
    path.transform(matrix)
    addPath(path.asComposePath())
}

Button(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface),
    border = BorderStroke(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface),
    onClick = {},
    elevation = null,
    shape = shape
) {}
```

still the visual result is the same (and maybe there is a better way to to this than using the *android.graphics.Path* type)

I also went on the Modifier.draw track with this approach:

```kotlin
Spacer(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .drawWithCache {
        val path = PathParser.createPathFromPathData("M 37.175 165 C 70 135 120 155 140.87 175 C 136.5 190 135.5 210 135 217.435 C 85 270 90 280 35 217.428 Q 64 194.5 37.175 165 Z")
        val matrix = Matrix()
        val scale = minOf(size.width / initialSVG_Width, size.height / initialSVG_Height)
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale)
        path.transform(matrix)
        val composePath = path.asComposePath()
        
        onDrawWithContent {
            drawPath(path = composePath, color = Color.Green, style = Fill)
            drawPath(path = composePath, color = Color.Black, style = Stroke(width = 2f))
        }
    }
    .clickable {
        // just to illustrate click event
        Toast.makeText(context, "Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    },
)
```

Here the visual result is as expected:
[visual ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMrx7.png)

But the toast event is raised even if I do not click on the green area.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a shaper correctly that abides dimensions of Composable will also create correct border which can be done by using a Path and scaling Path to Composable size using Matrix.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question using a path scaled with a matrix and tried to apply it on the button. I suppose the button borderStroke is guilty for this behaviour, but i do not find a way to display a colored border only by giving it the shape.